# WebStorm + Angular 9, control click on component

Tags: angular, webstorm

I'm new in Angular, I come from ReactJS. In WebStorm, in React, I can <kbd>Ctrl + Click</kbd> a component in the `render` method and I can navigate to that component code/file, it doesn't matter if it's comes from `node_modules` or my own components/code:

[image]

I wanted to do the same on Angular, in the html file, but it doesn't work:

[image]

Then here:

[image]

Is there a way to navigate to the component? I'm pretty tired of selecting the `selector` and then searching it on the whole `src` folder, the open the component that has that `selector`.

Comment: Did you install the angular plugin?

Comment: Lol, that was the reason. I disabled it some months ago, because I was trying to use only specific plugins for React, but I started with Angular yesterday. Thanks man.

Comment: Have you imported MapEventsComponent in the module where you declared BuscadorEventosComponent?

Comment: @yurzui it was the Angular plugin that was disabled as David said